# How to know facebook user id using email id only?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have email addresses of facebook user ,
i want to know user name / user id using email id ,
how it is possible ?,
actually i need to show Facebook profile image using Email ids 
thanks in advance.
****The process : (a) Emaild -> (b) User ID -> (c) profile image ****
*process (b)->(c) is completed by me , it is working successfully.
I need help in process (a)->(b)*

Thanks in advance.

can anyone know  how spokeo.com work  
it can featch facebook profile image using email id 
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible for your application to search user via his email. You can find out certain user's email (if you have his uid and permission to access email), but not the other way around.

Comment: OK , it is not possible ,
but how http://www.spokeo.com/ work 
it can featch facebook profile image using email id

Answer (score 1):

it is possible, you need to perform a search using Graph API

`https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=EMAIL&type=user&access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN`

you can test it in the [Graph API Explorer tool](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer)

BUT: pay attention that this may not work for people with high privacy level

Comment: it is not working properly...
please check

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=julia.humphries2010@gmail.com&type=user&access_token=AAACEdEose0cBAE65hn8ZBYI0xLzyaH5EhWibKIAfZA2SAtgWtn7AYuG7jRR5cpTJSZBHNKaYHIr55pi9ZAARLSy2Tu5H9Y9M8NbIp1zTKDWvJvmlzKNm&fields=id,name,email

it is showing blank data array

Comment: it will work when you place an email of your facebook friend .

Comment: as I mentioned - this is not a matter of friends - this is a matter of the user's privacy settings, which most of the time will be suffice for friends

Comment: OK ,
but how http://www.spokeo.com/ work 
it can featch facebook profile image using email id